# How to express the Boolean cardinality constraint to CNF formulas

Tags: encoding, sat

A Boolean cardinality constraint
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x_j=k,$$
where $x_j$’s are Boolean
variables, and $k$ is a non-negative integer.

How to express the Boolean cardinality constraint to CNF formulas?

Comment: Any idea of $n$ and $k$ ? For some values ($k=0$, $k=n$) that's a single line. In general, one option is to build a tree of adders.

Comment: https://carstensinz.de/papers/CP-2005.pdf